# What preference key to set java compiler compliance preference?

Tags: eclipse

A specific plug-in in my (branded) Eclipse-distribution requires java 1.6, but I really want java 1.5 to be the default java compiler compliance setting (because the Eclipse-distro is, among other things, being used for Android application development).

I bundle a java-6 jre, then the Eclipse disto is launched using that jre, which is exactly what I want, but then the java compiler compliance setting is also java 1.6, which I don't want.

Does anyone know how I can achieve so that the java compiler compliance setting is 1.5? I know it's easy to do the setting manually once Eclipse is started, but if I'd like it to be there by default, so that the user wouldn't have to set it him/herself?

I thought the answer could be plugin_customization.ini of my branding-plugin, but I already have it there, and it doesn't work.

org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.5
org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.5

But since the bundled jre is 1.6, these settings somehow get overridden. I will try configurations.epf now.

Any ideas, thoughts or hints are most welcome!

Comment: Have you followed this: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-assign_default_jre.htm

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is how to do it "manually". However, I want it to be done automatically (during build) of my branded eclipse-distro, so that once a user starts the distibution up, it's already done. That's what I don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out configurations.epf was the trick! It did work to specify java compiler compliance in the configuration-plugin (the configurations.epf).

I put these lines in my `configuration.epf`:

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.5
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.5
```

Now when starting the Eclipse-distribution it is launched using jre 1.6, but compiler compliance etc is set to 1.5 "by default", exactly like I wanted!